# django-rest-framework ignores fields from model mixin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following configuration of django models with base classes and a mixin for additional fields, but `django-rest-framework` is ignoring the fields from the mixin class.

**Models**

```py
from django.db import models

class Base(models.Model):
  a = CharField()

  class Meta:
    abstract = True


class Mixin(object):
  b = CharField()


class Concrete(Base, Mixin):
  c = CharField()

  class Meta(Base.Meta):
    abstract = False
```

**Serializers**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class BaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  class Meta:
    fields = ('a',)
    abstract = True

class ConcreteSerializer(BaseSerializer):
  class Meta(BaseSerializer.Meta):
    model = Concrete
    fields = ('b', 'c',)
```

**View sets**

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

class BaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  # Some common @actions here.

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class ConcreteViewSet(BaseViewSet):
  serializer_class = ConcreteSerializer

  class Meta(EquipmentItemEditProposalViewSet.Meta):
    abstract = False
```

**URLS**

```py
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'concrete', ConcreteViewSet, basename='concrete')
```

However, when I browese to http://localhost/api/concrete/ I get the `django-rest-framework` form with the `a` and `c` fields, but not the `b` field from the mixin.

**NOTE**: if I make the `Mixin` class inherig from `django.db.models.Model` instead of `object`, then I do get the field, but I that won't work because applying a django migration results in a diamond inheritance problem:

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Model, Mixin
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: what makes things work is if I explicitly add the fields to the `Mixin` to the `BaseSerializer`. However this is not as DRY as I'd like.

**EDIT 2**: this more serious than I thought: it's not that `django-rest-framework` is not picking up the field from `Mixin`, but it's actually that the field from the `Mixin` is not on the `Concrete` model at all. It's missing in the migration and it's not in the database schema. So my question becomes: how can I make the fields from `Mixin` actually be in `Concrete`?

Comment: Did you add abstract=True to Mixin.Meta? There should be non issue inheriting from multiple abstract models

Comment: @IainShelvington I just tried and it didn't help, still get the same `TypeError` if I try to do `makemigrations`.

Comment: @IainShelvington I was wrong, your solution works!